# Ruby on Rails not recognizing User model param[:number]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, models, twilio

I am trying to create an app using ruby on rails that will take a user given phone number, and then use Twilio's api to send a text message to that phone.  I don't think the problem is with the api because it seems as though it is not saving the number when the user enters it.  Here is my Users Controller Class: 
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Your daily insight is on its way!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
  end

  def send_text_message
      insightful_quotes = [
        'You will never reach your destination if you stop and throw    stones at every dog that barks. - Winston Churchill',
        'If you think adventure is dangerous, try routine.  It’s fatal. - Paulo Coelho',
        'Stay Hungry.  Stay Foolish. - Steve Jobs',
        'Darkness cannot drive out darkness; only light can do that. Hate cannot drive out hate, only love can do that.  Martin Luther King Jr.',
        'It’s better to have a short life that is full of what you like doing, than a long life spent in a miserable way. - Alan Watts',
        'Unless someone like you cares a whole awful lot, nothing is going to get better.  It’s not. - Dr. Seuss',
        'Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow.  The important thing is not to stop questioning. - Albert Einstein',
        'And those who were seen dancing were thought to be insane by those who could not hear the music. - Friedrich Nietzsche',
        'This world is but a canvas to our imagination. - Henry David Thoreau',
        'Do not go where the path may lead, go instead where there is no path and leave a trail. - Ralph Waldo Emerson',
        'Life is what happens while you are busy making other plans. - John Lennon',
        'There is nothing so stable as change. - Bob Dylan',
        'It is not in the stars to hold our destiny but in ourselves. - William Shakespeare',
        'Learning never exhausts the mind. - Leonardo da Vinci',
        'Be as you wish to seem. - Socrates',
        'Quality is not an act, it is a habit. - Aristotle'
    ] 
    random_quote = insightful_quotes[rand(insightful_quotes.size)]
  #  if @user.save
      number_to_send_to = params[:number]

      twilio_sid = "........"
      twilio_token = "........"
      twilio_phone_number = "......."

      @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_sid, twilio_token

      @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => "+1#{twilio_phone_number}",
      :to => number_to_send_to,
      :body => "#{random_quote}"
      )
      puts "Your quote is on its way."
  #  end
  end

  helper_method :send_text_message

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:number)
    end
end
```

Then in view for 'show' I call the 'send_text_message' using '<%= send_text_message %>

Here is the model class User for accepting the number:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.number = number.gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }
  validates :number, presence: true
  validates_format_of :number,
  :with => %r{(1)?(?:-)?(?:\(|-)?([\d]{3})(?:\.|\-|\))?([\d]{3}) (?:\.|\-)?([\d]{4})(?: ?x([\d]{3,5}))?},
  :message => "should be a phone number"
end
```

This is my routes file (I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and know little about routing:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'

  get 'users/new'
  root 'users#new'
  get 'send_text_message' => 'users#send_text_message'
  resources :users
```

Now my desire for this program is that when the user enters a phone number, it will direct them to a thank you page (I have that templated in html in the show file and know that it works. It stopped working only when I added the 'send_text_message' function.) and then it will send a random quote from the array of quotes to their phone, but the error I keep getting is:

ActionView::Template::Error (A 'To' phone number is required.)

The 'To' number should be getting grabbed from the user model using the params[:number], right?

I am very lost and have been working for 9 hours trying to figure this out and have absolutely no clue what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't grab it from the user model using params[:number], it will get it from the parameters hash if you pass it, but the parameters are changed with each request, when you create a user they won't just hang around as you click through the rest of the site.

I'd change your routes to:

```
resources :users do
  get 'send_text_message', on: :member
end
```

Then you can do this in your action

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
number_to_send_to = @user.number
```

This will mean your url will be `/users/:id/send_text_message` and the path will change to be this when you link to it `send_text_message_user_path(some_user_id)`

You should consider refactoring that action though.

Comment: Which method in controller would I put "@user = User.find(params[:id])
number_to_send_to = @user.number" If I put it in the show method, how do I access it from the send_text_message method? Sorry I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Put it in the `send_text_message` action